# Controlling data step in a list in python

Tags: python, sensors

Let's suppose I have data from a sensor, in the format:

```
data = [100, 140, 200, 250, 210, 300, 350, 380, 400, 333, 352, 399, 599, 899]
```

I want to loose resolution from this data so that I can modify its format in C++ later for the embedded device.

I want to force the resolution of the data. For example: no step must be lower than 50, then, all values have to be round up or down, I don't care, a multiply of 50. The result must be:

```
data = [100, 150, 200, 250, 250, 300, 350, 400, 400, 350, 400, 400, 600, 900]
```

I tried this code:

```
def curate_data(data: list, step_size: int = 1000):
    def _round(number, increment, offset):
        return round((number - offset) / increment) * increment + offset

    curated_data = [data[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        append_value = int(data[i])
        if data[i] - curated_data[-1] < step_size:
            # round to nearest multiple of step_size
            append_value = _round(number=data[i], increment=step_size, offset=0)
        curated_data.append(append_value)
    return curated_data
```

but it does not generate the result I am expecting.

How could I manage this data to have the required resolution? Thanks

Comment: Why does 352 become 360 and not 400?

Comment: typo, fixed. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This can be done in one line of code, except rounding 352 to 360 breaks the logic. Everything else is being rounded to a multiple of 50.

Comment: right, but this is just one general example. The real case is much difficult but lets start from the bottom

Comment: @GabrielGaleote-Checa Then, please, provide a meaningful test set that includes edge cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use floordiv and recalculate. You stated that you don't care if it rounds up or down. This will round according to the rules round is expected to follow.

```
data = [100, 140, 200, 250, 210, 300, 350, 380, 400, 333, 352, 399, 599, 899]
  
# round integers to multiples of step
def iround_by(num:int, step:int=50) -> int:
    return int((step/2+num)//step*step)
    
out = list(map(iround_by, data))
    
print(out)
```

###### output

```
[100, 150, 200, 250, 200, 300, 350, 400, 400, 350, 350, 400, 600, 900]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I can modify the step to any other value. I have tried with 100 and 1000. As long as I manage the data type to be of same format as step size (same units) Ican convert the data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to figure out if the original value is a multiple of 50. If it is then there's nothing to be done, otherwise some simple arithmetic gives you what you want:

```
data = [100, 140, 200, 250, 210, 300, 350, 380, 400, 333, 352, 399, 599, 899]

def roundup(n):
    if (r := n % 50) != 0:
        return n + 50 - r
    return n

print(list(map(roundup, data)))
```

**Output:**

```
[100, 150, 200, 250, 250, 300, 350, 400, 400, 350, 400, 400, 600, 900]
```

Comment: This also worked perfectly. A bit more raw-ish implementation but functional. Thanks!